using c# language replace images inside a word document?
I need to replace image with another image from computer inside word document using c# language?
I used the below code to replace a text inside a word document Now I need to use this code to replace images inside word using c# languages please help me
`
object filename = Path.Combine(System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath, "D:\\dpucertificates\\DPU.CERTIFICATES\\cer_samples\\col_ar_male.docx");
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application wordapp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application { Visible = true };
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document aDoc = wordapp.Documents.Open(ref filename, ReadOnly: false, Visible: true);
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Find fnd = wordapp.ActiveWindow.Selection.Find;
    
    fnd.Wrap = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdFindWrap.wdFindContinue;
    fnd.Text = "@name@";
    name = tname.Text;
    String s = name.Trim();
    fnd.Replacement.Text = s;
    fnd.Execute(Replace: WdReplace.wdReplaceAll);
fnd.Text = "@sadr@";
fnd.Replacement.Text =shortyear+ttest.Text;
fnd.Execute(Replace: WdReplace.wdReplaceAll);`


What kind of picture do you need to replace, there must be some rules or reference data, otherwise, how do you know which image to replace? Or is your Word document only a picture? We can only track and compare the image by its index value or properties such as AlternativeText. How can we do it if we don't know the characteristics of the object we want to replace?

my word document contains JPG image behind texts so I need replace x  image with another image

What's the meaning of ' JPG image behind texts '? Would you like to show me a sample?
